# Rails: validation between columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

Assume, we have a model, let's call it Articles. There, we have two columns, **min** and **max**. The rule is: **min** can't be greater or equal to **max**. How do you resolve this custom type of validation? Any ideas?

Going further, let's assume that we have columns **character** and **made_of**. Task is to create a validation which is gonna help to avoid a situation, when "character = human" and "made_of = steel".

Is there are standard routines to manage "metaphysical" conflicts between columns?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use validate to define your own validations. For instance:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :min_greater_than_max, :humans_aint_made_of_steel

  def min_greater_than_max
    errors.add(:min, "can't be greater than max") if min > max
  end 

  def humans_aint_made_of_steel
    errors.add(:human, "can't be made of steel") if character == 'human' && made_of == 'steel'
  end

end
```

Comment: You bet @gmile, although I am made of steel, and I happen to be human as well ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is generic method `validate` which can take care of your all validations between columns. Be careful though, looks like your needs for validations require lots of testing.